# Doxygen-like equation writing in html

Tags: html, latex, doxygen

Doxygen has the ability to produce code with inline equations with LaTeX (I am a TeXnician). I want to do the same thing just for html pages. How can I achieve this? What does doxygen use to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) or [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/)?  They're two JavaScript libraries that let you embed LaTeX, if you know it.

Comment: Thanks. MathJax is exactly what I need, works much better that the image version of doxygen. Now I just need to worry about the massive font directory now :-(